# Find a number $A$ so that $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$ are always odd

Tags: number-theory, closed-form

Find a  number  $A$ so that

- (1) $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor$ is always odd for $n\geq 1$;($\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the largest integer not greater than $x.$)
- (2) $A>1$ and $A^{3^n}$ is never an integer for $n\geq 1$;(This is the place I have edited.)
- (3) There is a [closed-form formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $A.$(Series and integral can also be seen as a closed form.)

[Mills' constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) satisfies (1) and (2) but not (3) (so far).

We can construct a number satisfies (1) and (2) more easily than Mills' constant:

Let $a_1=1,a_{n+1}=a_n^3+2~(n\geq1).$ Denote $$A=\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{3^n}}.$$
Then we can prove that $\lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor=a_n,$ hence $A>1$ and $a_n$ is odd. The proof is very like to [this](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1947-53-06/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2/S0002-9904-1947-08849-2.pdf). But I cannot find a closed-form formula for $A$ again.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: $$A=3^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

Comment: @Ethan You are right!..But please forgive me to change my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For any integer $m \ge 2$, let $A = m + \sqrt{m^2-1}$ and define a sequence $(T_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ by:

$$T_n = A^n + A^{-n}$$

It is easy to see $T_0 = 2$, $T_1 = 2m$ and $T_{n+2} = 2mT_{n+1} - T_{n}$ for any $n \ge 0$. From this, we can conclude $T_n$ is an even integer for any $n \ge 0$.

It is also clear $A > 1$ and hence for all $n \ge 1$, we have:

$$\begin{align}0 < A^{-(3^n)} < 1 \implies & T_{3^n} - 1 < A^{3^n} = T_{3^n} - A^{-(3^n)} < T_{3^n}\\ \implies & \lfloor A^{3^n} \rfloor = T_{3^n} - 1 \text{ is an odd integer.}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you!It seems that $3^n$ can be replaced with $n.$

Comment: Yes, $3^n$ can be replaced with $n$.